# Should 'sharing', 'copy' and 'text' be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've come across the following tags:

- [sharing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sharing)
- [copy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/copy) / [paste](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/paste)
- and [text](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/text)

It is my opinion that these tags should be completely removed from the system as they are too ambiguous.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Not enough to make an answer, but kill em all!

Comment: @JorgeCastro "Kill em all" is an acceptable answer :)

Answer (score 5):

**In regards to [copy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/copy)...**

[image: Aw, yeah!]

Seriously though, I edited the tag out of every single one of those questions. I realize that moderators have access to a tool that greatly simplifies this, but I really wanted an excuse to post that image :P

Comment: Great job! That was no small task.

Comment: We have access to tools? I haven't found anything like this Nathan....

Comment: @jrg: I was *sure* there was a tool for that, but I just checked and indeed, I can't find anything.

Comment: I nearly thought I was being slack,